# Live load contribution in total energy of elastic plate

Tags: mechanical-engineering, mathematics

I study a model for plate bending due to tangential live load applied to its upper surface $x_3=h$. After deformation the load remains tangential to the deformed upper surface. What would then be the contribution of the load to the plate energy? My guess is
$$
\int_{\Gamma_h}\boldsymbol\sigma_h:\nabla{\bf r}_hd\boldsymbol x,
$$
but not sure.

Any guess, reference or hint?